# For $R(t)$ symmetric, prove $\int_0^T \int_0^T R(t-s) \; dt \; ds = \frac{2}{T^2} \int_0^T (T-u) R(u) \; du$

Tags: calculus

Suppose $R(t) \in L^1$ is symmetric: $R(t) = R(-t)$. Show that
$$\int_0^T \int_0^T R(t-s) \; dt \; ds = \frac{2}{T^2} \int_0^T (T-u) R(u) \; du$$

This is an exam problem, but I believe it is incorrect. The $T^2$ should not be on the denominator. My solution was to integrate diagonal slices. We can do this for half the slices (those with intercept above $0$) by symmetry. Then the measure changes to $1/\sqrt{2} \; dx dy$, which cancels out with the $\sqrt{2}$ factor of the length of the diagonal. Then this gives the result with the $T^2$ removed. Can anyone verify this?

Comment: That $T^2$ in the denominator on the right sounds fishy. Instead of integrating over the square by vertical and horizontal strips, integrate along the _diagonals_ along which $R(t-s)$ has constant value $R(u)$ and the diagonal is of length $\sqrt{2}(T-u)$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its stated correctly??

Let $R(t)=1.$ It surely satisfies all the good conditions but $\int_0^T \int_{0}^{T} R(t-s)\,dt\,ds=T^2$ while $\frac{2}{T^2} \int_{0}^{T}(T-u) R(u)\,du=\frac{2}{T^2}\int_0^T(T-u)\,du=1$

Comment: on a bright side they didnt proof a FALSE statement. this equality seems too good to be true. Even without that $T^2$ still wrong. Im trying to see how we can rectify it.